# How to insert slideshow controllers into a div properly using DOM

Tags: javascript, css, dom, append, slideshow

I'm trying to insert the left and right controllers on the two ends of my slideshow div via the DOM such that they are on the opposite ends of the slideshow div

So far I've only gotten them either to display in the top corners of the browser window (Using **top: 0; left: 0** and **top: 0; right: 0** for the right and left controller id's style formatting) or where the left controller displays where it should, but the right controller displays directly below the left controller rather than on the opposite side of the slideshow div (I did this by changing the right and left controller styles to float in place of the previous formatting that I just mentioned)

I feel like it might have something to do with the styling, but I could be horribly wrong.
Anyone have any ideas?

HTML:

```
  <div id="pageContainer">

 <!-- Slideshow HTML -->
  <div id="slideShow" style="border-style: solid; border-color: red; border-width: 1px;">
    <div id="slidesContainer" style="border-style: solid; border-color: yellow; border-width: 1px;">

      <div class="slide">

        <h2>Web Development With PHP</h2>
        <p><a href="#"><img src="newphp.JPG" alt="Screen capture of PHP built website" width="215" height="145" /></a></p>

      </div>

      <div class="slide">

        <h2>Database Design with MySQL Workbench</h2>
        <p><a href="file:///C:/Users/Owner/Documents/IRWireframe/experience.html#test"><img src="Patient_Database_Snapshot.JPG" width="215" height="145" alt="MySQL Workbench Database Design Snapshot" /></a></p>

      </div>

      <div class="slide">

        <h2>Web Design With CSS and HTML</h2>
        <p><a href="#"><img src="webdesign.JPG" width="215" height="145" alt="Screen capture of Brian Houlhan's CSS webpage" /></a></p>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div> 
  <!-- Slideshow HTML -->

  </div>
```

CSS:

```
/*
 * Slideshow style rules.
 */
#slideShow {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:640px;
    height:263px;
    background:transparent url(bg_slideshow.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
    position:relative;
}
#slideShow #slidesContainer {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:560px;
  height:263px;
  overflow:auto; /* allow scrollbar */
  position:relative;
}
#slideShow #slidesContainer .slide {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:540px; /* reduce by 20 pixels of #slidesContainer to avoid horizontal scroll */
  height:263px;
}

/** 
 * Slideshow controls style rules.
 */
.control {
  display: block;
  width: 39px;
  height:263px;
  text-indent:-10000px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#leftControl {
  float: left;
  /*
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  */
  background:transparent url(control_left.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
#rightControl {
 float: right;
 /*
 top: 0;
 right: 0;

*/
  background:transparent url(control_right.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Javascript (Running in HTML document):

```
  // Insert controls in the DOM
  $('#slideShow')
    .prepend('<span class="control" id="leftControl">Clicking moves left</span>')
    .append('<span class="control" id="rightControl">Clicking moves right</span>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work just fine:

```
#slideshow{
position:relative;
}
#leftControl{
float:none;
top:0;
left:0;
}
#rightControl{
float:none;
top:0;
left:0;
}
```

of course you dont need to add the float none, you could just simply remove the float:left and float:right that is currently on those elements.

Comment: Thank you! It wasn't working when I first tried it but after I got rid of the test borders it looked perfect

Answer (score 0):

When the controls are positioned with absolute positioning -

```
.control {
  display: block;
  width: 39px;
  height:263px;
  text-indent:-10000px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#leftControl {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background:#ff0000;
}
#rightControl {
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
  background:#ffcc00;
}
```

I am not seeing an error in how it is being displayed. If you look here http://jsfiddle.net/CERFY/ it looks correct. Is there some other markup that could be affecting this, that maybe you had a live example to show?

Comment: Here is my test site that shows how its messing up: http://2011.ispace.ci.fsu.edu/~bch09c/TestSite/index.html